# How to make fimplicit3 show all solutions?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot the following (3-D) implicit surface: [image] using `fimplicit3`. The image should be something like
[image: Figure 1],
but when I use

```
f = @(x,y,z) (x.^6-x.^4);
fimplicit3(f,'EdgeColor','none','FaceAlpha',.5)
grid off
```

I got the following image

[image: Figure 2].

So I do not know why the plane `x=0` has been ignored here and what is going wrong.

Comment: Image link is broken

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! Now it is fixed!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing going wrong. Your first picture is not the surface of [image].

If your implicit surface is a `x`-only polynomial consisting exclusively of even exponents, there will be no plane at `x=0`.

Reason is, that at `x=0` your function has an even number of zeros (in this case four times `x^4=0`), since [image].

If you project the problem on two dimensions this means a corresponding graph has a root which is only touching `x=0` but not intersecting it, while an uneven polynomial would intersect `x=0`.

Therefore, if you use `fimplicit3` with an uneven implicit polynomial function

```
fimplicit3(@(x,y,z) x.^5 - x.^3, 'EdgeColor','none','FaceAlpha',.5)
```

it will lead to your expectation, while every even polynomial, e.g.

```
fimplicit3(@(x,y,z) x.^4 - x.^2, 'EdgeColor','none','FaceAlpha',.5)
```

won't. See here:

[image]